# FSharp pattern that matches List type

Tags: list, f#, pattern-matching

I want to match the object obj1 of type "obj" according to its actual type.
The problem is that the type check pattern for list type (the second one in the example below) does not match F# lists.

```
let obj1 = [1;2;3] :> obj
match obj1 with
    | :? System.Array as a -> printfn "it's an array: %A" a
    | :? List<_> as l -> printfn "It's a list: %A" l
    | _ -> printfn "other type"
```

Outputs "other type", while I expect it to be "It's a list: [1;2;3]"

How to check for list type properly?

Comment: There is an infinite set of types that could work for `_` here, so surely it is being generalized to `obj`..

Comment: But why `:? List<_>` does not match? It goes first.

Comment: _`List<obj>`_ does not match, as it shouldn't. I believe you'll have to use reflection to get this to work.

Comment: This even issues a warning (and editor squiggles, if you are in VS) telling you exactly what @ildjarn says: `~vs358F.fsx(4,15): warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' or other type annotation at or near 'filename.fsx(4,14)-(4,15)' has been constrained to be type 'obj'.
other type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Fabian has already explained the problem in his answer.

One way to implement his solution is with an [Active Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|IsList|_|) (candidate : obj) =
    let t = candidate.GetType()
    if t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<list<_>>
    then Some (candidate :?> System.Collections.IEnumerable)
    else None
```

You can now change the match to use this active pattern:

```
let obj1 = [1;2;3] :> obj
match obj1 with
    | :? System.Array as a -> printfn "it's an array: %A" a
    | IsList l -> printfn "It's a list: %A" l
    | _ -> printfn "other type"
```

This prints:

```
> It's a list: [1; 2; 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
obj : [any type]
```

What you need to do, is distinguish if your obj is a generic type. Get the type of it by means of `.GetType()` there you'll find the appropriate property.

```
obj : [some type of the form T<'T1, 'T2, ..., 'Tn> for concrete types T1, T2, ..., Tn]
```

If it is, then you get the generic type definition by using the appropritate method on the type you got by means of `.GetType()`

```
obj : [some type of the form T<'T1, 'T2, ..., 'Tn> with T1, T2, ..., Tn not bound yet]
```

and this type you now can compare to `typedefof<_ list>` (`_ list` is inferred to be `obj list`, but `typedefof` as opposed to `typeof` does the getting of generic type definition for you already).

The final code looks something like this (pseudo-code)

```
let ty = obj.GetType()
match obj with
| unknownType when not ty.IsGenericType -> "some non-generic type, probably a concrete collection"
| list when ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ list> -> "list"
| array when ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ array> -> "array"
| _ -> "something else, i.e. a generic type that we don't know"
```

Answer (score -2):

I would not call List<_> as F# list - it is .NET framework type. You can match it with (int list) type - it is F# list:

```
match obj1 with | :? (int list) as l -> 1 | _ -> 0
```

Comment: Actually I don't know what the list element type is. I just have object of class "obj".

So the question: is it possible to match F# list of any element type with pattern matching?

Comment: Not - `List` will only resolve to `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` if you have `open`ed the relevant namespace, otherwise it does actually resolve to the F# list.